# Typescript Issue - Typescript dosen't Infer object properties

Tags: typescript

I have a trouble with Typescript
I am trying to infer the properties of an Object dynamically.

take a look at the below code

```
const Actions = {
    globalUI: {
        openModal: 'openModal'
    }
}

type Param = keyof typeof Actions;
type T = <T, K extends keyof T>(action: T, key: K) => T[K];
const fn = (param: Param) => {

    const action = mapper(Actions, param);

    return action
}
const mapper:T = (action, name) => {
    return action[name]
}

const action = fn('globalUI');
```

[image]

as you can see Typescript can infer a global UI properties

but When I put the additional property in the Actions Object
[image]

Typescript doesn't infer Object properties

```
const Actions = {
    globalUI: {
        openModal: 'openModal'
    },
    LP: {
        addDirectory: 'addDirectory'
    }
}

type Param = keyof typeof Actions;
type T = <T, K extends keyof T>(action: T, key: K) => T[K];
const fn = (param: Param) => {

    const action = mapper(Actions, param);

    return action
}
const mapper:T = (action, name) => {
    return action[name]
}

const action = fn('globalUI');
```

[image]

How can I achieve it?
please give any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapper function works as expected :

```
type T = <T, K extends keyof T>(action: T, key: K) => T[K];

const mapper:T = (action, name) => {
    return action[name]
}

const action = mapper(Actions, 'globalUI');

action.openModel // works greak
```

The problem lies in the `fn` function which infers a union as a return type.
`{ openModal: string } | { addDirectory: string }` in your example.

So you need to explicit the return type with a generic :

```
const fn = <S extends Param>(param: S): typeof Actions[S]  => {
    const action = mapper(Actions, param);
    return action
}

const action = fn('globalUI'); 

action.globalUI; // Ok now
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAgsKBLcEYF4YG8BQN8wDmANiAEYCGxAqgJIBc2eBLIADgKZgCyIAJlUYBydl14DiQ5vgC%20AGmkwAMgAVGuFiwp8%20AESQAnDohAGAnsO17DxqKbNSWMnM5xQznGCooGKAWwwYAGsOMxAAMxh3Tgj4RBRIAG43Dw4YABVAgB50uRgAaRgOAA8oLj40ELDI9IA%20AAoKePBGXODQxnyASgxajIBtfIBdZJxQSFhwsGyAZSLS8rRvXz8Gth9-RhmuxmiOWIRkVH6Zofx0PtxFcegYJqPpzD8KNk4DesOEiDz1la7RlhGKAAVwM03uCRcY1QsGerw4BnomUwjWaYDyYH8HB6FyYgI4ILBdzR-Uxfg4Qyh0ImxIegSm9SEJHIVDoQn%20OBwQA)